# JQuery datepicker adds a new button next to textbox

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a textbox and a dropdown menu. Based on the selected value from dropdown menu, I change the textbox to a datepicker field, if necessary. The functionality works fine, but I am seeing that there is a small button between the textbox and dropdown when the datepicker is activated. It vanishes when the datepicker is destroyed.

When I used firebug to look at the HTML, I am seeing the following lines being added

```
<button class="ui-datepicker-trigger" type="button">
      <img src="/images/drop-down.gif" alt="..." title="...">
</button>
```

Any idea how I can get rid of this button and just trigger the datepicker calendar when user clicks on the textbox?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that comes from using this option to `datepicker`:

```
buttonImage: '/images/drop-down.gif'
```

If you don't want a button, don't use that option.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't give the following propeties when you bind the textbox with datepicker

```
 buttonImage: 'images/icon_calendar.gif',
 buttonImageOnly: true,
```